# Do i need to have a business paypal account to develop an app?

Tags: xamarin, paypal

I am about to implement paypal express checkout with paypal.forms for a PCL xamarin app and it requires a paypal ID for the setup

what im asking is do i need a business developer account to get a paypalID to make apps? or can i do that with a regular paypal account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, Yes you do. You are able to create a personal app then sign in into Paypal developer portal but there's not much you can do once there. The Paypal developer API is meant to business transactions.

You can read more of this in their [FAQ](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/faq/) section.

Hope this helps!